# java nio and FileInputStream

Tags: java, performance, gzip, nio

Basically I have this code to decompress some string that stores in a file:

```
public static String decompressRawText(File inFile) {
    InputStream in = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(STRING_SIZE);
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(in, BUFFER_SIZE);
        in = new GZIPInputStream(in, BUFFER_SIZE);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = isr.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
            sb.append(cbuf, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Since physical IO is quite time consuming, and since my compressed version of files are all quite small(around 2K from 2M of text), is it possible for me to still do the above, but on a file that is already mapped to memory? possibly using java NIO? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It won't make any difference, at least not much. Mapped files are about 20% faster in I/O last time I looked. You still have to actually *do* the I/O: mapping just saves some data copying. I would look at increasing `BUFFER_SIZE` to at least 32k. Also the size of `cbuf`, which should be a local variable in this method, not a member variable, so it will be thread-safe. It might be worth *not* compressing the files under a certain size threshold, say 10k.

Also you should be closing `isr` here, not `in`.

It *might* be worth trying putting another BufferedInputStream on top of the GZIPInputStream, as well as the one underneath it. Get it to do more at once.